# Is it more pythonic to use fewer lines of code?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I've figured out two ways to do the same thing and am wondering which is better and why.

Input = postal package weight

Output = the cheapest shipping method and price as a string

The methods below take 1 argument, "weight" and are meant to compare "Ground", "Drone", and "Premium" pricing and then return a string that gives the cheapest shipping method and price. (Earlier in the program methods are defined for "ground_rate(weight)" and "drone_rate(weight)"... prem_groud_rate is a constant float value.)

**First way uses a dictionary:**

```
def shipping_method_determiner(weight):
  prices = {"Ground": ground_rate(weight), "Drone": drone_rate(weight), "Premium" : prem_ground_rate}
  cheapest_method = (list(prices.keys())[list(prices.values()).index(sorted(prices.values())[0])])
  return (("%s is the cheapest method.\n\n" % cheapest_method) + ("The total cost will be %.2f.\n" % sorted(prices.values())[0]))
```

**Second way ends up using a list of tuples:**

```
def shipping_method_determiner(weight):
  method_list = ["Ground", "Drone", "Premium"]
  price_list = [ground_rate(weight), drone_rate(weight), prem_ground_rate]
  min_price = min(price_list)
  method_with_price = list(zip(method_list, price_list))
  best_method = (method_with_price[price_list.index(min_price)][0])
  return "%s is the cheapest method.\n\nThe total cost will be %.2f \n" % (best_method, min_price)
```

The first way only uses 4 lines but seems harder to read. The second way easier to read but almost twice as many lines. Is it always more pythonic to go for readability over fewer lines? Any other ways to define this method and get the same result? Would it be better to somehow use .format() instead of string formatting?

Thank you, all you smart people!

Comment: "Sparse is better than dense. Readability counts." –The Zen of Python

Comment: First: "pythonicity" is a very subjective quality that can easily misinform how to write code in the best possible way. Second, no, not as a general rule. The zen of Python is all about making things simple, readable and less error-prone. That sometimes mean using fewer lines (less "mass of code" to read, less place for errors), but not necessarily.

Comment: Ok I guess that makes a good case for the list way. Anyone know a cleaner way to do this though. My gut tells me its clunkier than it needs to be.

Comment: For future reference, this sort of question is more suited for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I wrote in the comment above, shorter code does not necessarily make for more pythonic code. Simplicity, readibility and maintainability should be the main criteria to decide which version of the code to keep. About your particular problem, I think I would have gone with something like:

```
def shipping_method_determiner(weight):
  prices = {
    "Ground": ground_rate(weight),
    "Drone": drone_rate(weight),
    "Premium": prem_ground_rate,
  }
  best_method, min_price = min(prices.items(), key=lambda item: item[1])
  return "%s is the cheapest method.\n\nThe total cost will be %.2f \n" % (best_method, min_price)
```

Comment: For readability in Python 3.6+ (and minor efficiency), it's worth considering f-strings instead of `%` syntax. Also, IMO it's better to return values and construct the string separately. Separate "pure logic" and "nice string formatting".

Comment: @jpp Yes, I was only considering the "algorithmic" part of the problem (which I think is what the OP was having trouble to express tersely). But yes, f-strings would be nicer if you can use them, and "controller" and "view" concerns should probably be separated.

Comment: Ah ok. I need to get more comfy with lambda. Great answer, thanks!